# Can XenCenter connect to xen-hypervisor-amd64

Tags: virtualization, gui, xen

I have installed XenServer recently, but didn't stick with it. I am familiar with Ubuntu and was reading you can install XenHypervisor as a standalone package inside a Ubuntu OS. Kind of like installing Hyper-V on windows server instead of installing Hyper-V Server. The reason I stayed away from KVM is that I couldn't find a good GUI for management, but I liked XenCenter GUI for XenServer.

My question is:

If I installed Ubunutu Server 14.04 and then follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) to install  xen-hypervisor-amd64 could I use the XenCenter windows application to view/manage the Xen Hypervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at LibVirt and VirtManager, both completely free alternatives to XenCenter, and they support more hypervisors than Xen alone.

Ubuntu Server 14.04 should have the packages readily available via

```
 apt-get install libvirt0 virt-manager
```

Once done, fire up VirtManager from the command line with `virt-manager`. It should connect to your Xen daemon immediately if you're running Xen 4.2+ (where `xl` is the default toolstack).

If you're not running Xen 4.2+ (or are using `xm` as the toolstack), then you'll have to modify a few lines in `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` in order for LibVirt to connect to Xen:

```
 (xend-http-server yes)
 (xend-port 8000)
```

After making the above changes, run `service xen restart` and then run `service libvirt-bin restart` (or `service libvirtd restart` if `libvirt-bin` doesn't work). VirtManager should now connect successfully to Xen.

**HOWEVER**

If you really want XenCenter to work with your configuration, you will need to install the XCP/XAPI packages in the Ubuntu repository. These packages contain the `xe` (XenServer) toolstack to communicate with Xen, but they are **heavily outdated and no longer maintained**. They may have already been removed from the Ubuntu 14.04 repository as well.

More info on XCP/XAPI can be found here:

http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/XCP_Overview

[http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_/*XCP*/_XAPI_Overview](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_/_XCP_/_XAPI_Overview)

http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Project_Kronos `aims to provide the ability to install the XAPI toolstack onto a pre-existing OS deployment`

Hope this helps